# Dynamodb Local Connection with Java

Tags: java, maven, amazon-dynamodb

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.google.inject.PrivateModule;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;

 @Singleton
 public class AwsCredentialsModule extends PrivateModule {
   private final String m_accessKeyId;
   private final String m_secretKey;

   public AwsCredentialsModule() {
     m_accessKeyId = "youraccesskey";
     m_secretKey = "yoursecretkey";
  }

   @Override
   protected void configure() {
       expose(AWSCredentials.class);
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   private AWSCredentials provideAmazonCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(m_accessKeyId, m_secretKey);
   }
 }
```

It works for Dynamodb database. I am trying to connect with dynamodb-local  database.
Here we use MAVEN and Google Juice to build application and Google Protobuffer for interfacing.
Please find the way how to expose Dynamodb Local module using same framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not showing the definition of your DynamoDBClient. 
That's the element you need to "switch" when you want to work locally.

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(CredentialsManager.dummyCreds);

amazonDynamoDBClient.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000");
```

Comment: Yes It works, I'm tried using generic class AmazonDynamoDBClient

Comment: Does that mean you still have issues or could you accept my answer?